# JavaScript stops execution half way and evaluates wrong answer?, Console.log is correct

Tags: javascript, jquery

I didn't think this was possible until `console.log();` shown me that whats happening is impossible.

I can't understand how this is possible it's like those variables are being modified before code execution finishes.

I got this JavaScript code with debugging in it.

It's wrapped in this.

```
$('#buyAmountInput').keyup(function () {
        var buyAmount = parseFloat($(this).val());
        var totalPrice = 0;
        var max = $(this).attr("max");
        var min = $(this).attr("min");

        if (buyAmount != $(this).val()) {
            if (isNaN(buyAmount)) {
                buyAmount = 1;
                $(this).val('');
            } else {
                $(this).val(buyAmount);
            }
        } else {
            if (buyAmount > max) {
                buyAmount = max;
                $(this).val(buyAmount);
            } else if (buyAmount < min) {
                buyAmount = min;
                //$(this).val(buyAmount);
            }
        }
        totalPrice = buyAmount * unitPrice;
        //lots of code trimmed off here.


        largessAmount = Math.round(buyAmount * largessRule.rebate) / 100;
////
        console.log("Buy amount " + buyAmount + " LargessRebate " + largessRule.rebate);
        console.log("Total Price  " + totalPrice);
        console.log("Largess Amount " + largessAmount);
        console.log("New rate " + Number(totalPrice / (buyAmount + largessAmount)).moneyFormat());
        console.log("No .moneyFormat() New rate " + Number(totalPrice / (buyAmount + largessAmount)));
        console.log("( " + totalPrice + " / ( " + buyAmount + " + " + largessAmount + " ))");
////
        $('#unitPrice').html(Number(totalPrice / (buyAmount + largessAmount)).moneyFormat());
});
```

Debug looks like this

```
Buy amount 5000 LargessRebate 20
Total Price  4250
Largess Amount 1000
New rate 0.71
No .moneyFormat() New rate 0.7083333333333334
( 4250 / (5000 + 1000))


function fastKeyListener content_script.js:208

Buy amount 5000 LargessRebate 20
Total Price  4250
Largess Amount 1000
New rate 0.00 //<- What happened here
No .moneyFormat() New rate 0.00008499830003399932 //<- What happened here
( 4250 / (5000 + 1000)) //<- Third line executed this will give good rate..
```

Even if the variables are global and this code is in a keypress up jQuery callback function.
The variables are printed before they are executed by `console.log()` and they are correct but the answer is dead wrong.

Here is the moneyFormat() which I don't think could be the problem could it?

```
var effective_bit = -2;

Number.prototype.moneyFormat = function () {
    var num = this;
    sign = (num == (num = Math.abs(num)));
    num = Math.floor(num * Math.pow(10, -effective_bit) + 0.50000000001);
    cents = num % Math.pow(10, -effective_bit);
    num = Math.floor(num / Math.pow(10, -effective_bit)).toString();
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((num.length - (1 + i)) / 3); i++)
        num = num.substring(0, num.length - (4 * i + 3)) + ', ' + num.substring(num.length - (4 * i + 3));
    if (effective_bit < 0) {
        if (cents < 10 && effective_bit == '-2') cents = "0" + cents;
        money = (((sign) ? '' : '-') + num + '.' + cents);
    } else {
        money = (((sign) ? '' : '-') + num);
    }
    return money;
};
```

I didn't post the whole code as it's very large, but you can see it live [here](https://www.HighGamer.com)

Just put into the Unit to buy of 4999, then scroll to 5000 it's all good.. try putting like 5001 or 50000 it will reset it to 5000 and give wrong answer in the process.

**EDIT:**
 could of simplified the question to why does the `console.log()` functions evaluate incorrect answer if the same equation generated with the same variables just 1 line after in execution after gives correct answer, even on calculator.

Like some quantum going on here, bear with me there is nothing I could have done from 1 line to another line during that code-execution no breakpoints were set nothing plus those callbacks are functions generated in their own sandbox I believe so they are like ajax threads all working to complete sooner or later they all work separately from each other, so nothing working together here to mess it up. What you think could possibly happen here? some temporarily corruption or something?

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you are trying to do.  What do you expect the console output to say?

Comment: The `New Rate` shouldn't ever be `0.00` that's the problem, I edited the debug information showing the flaw, seems to happen when I move the slider over the maximum limit of 5000.

Comment: Ah. 

Number(x) where x is a false value will give you a zero.   If you add the debugging lines:

console.log((totalPrice / (buyAmount + largessAmount)).moneyFormat()), without the Number(), I'm certain you'll find it's undef or otherwise false.  So yeah, check your moneyFormat() function.

Comment: By the way, I'd be extremely careful about trying to bit-fiddle javascript numbers.   I don't think all versions of ECMA  JavaScript make guarantees about the particulars of the floating point system, so you may be writing supremely flaky/non-portable code...

Comment: @BadZen: it guarantees they are IEEE754 (but it still leaves some variations, indeed)

Comment: Meh it's from a framework that's worked by a community to me it's way ahead of my comprehension haha, but yeah it happens before the `moneyFormat` function, `(totalPrice / (buyAmount + largessAmount))` gives `0.00008499830003399932` instead of `0.7083333333333334`

Comment: @zerkms - Current ECMA does but IIRC that wasn't always true in previous versions...

Comment: I had the console.log showing the equation wrong but the issue still exists, But what I meant to say is if you look at that equation `console.log` prints `( 4250 / (5000 + 1000))` which suppose to always give `0.70833333333333333333333333333333` before the `moneyFormat` function but it gives `0.00008499830003399932` sometimes how can the variables be modified like that? first of all all those var's are inside the callback for keyup they are not global

Comment: I could of simplified the question to why does the console.log evaluate incorrect answer if the same equation generated with the same variables 1 line execution after gives correct answer, even on calculator. Like some quantum going on here, bare with me there is nothing I could of done from 1 line to another line during that code-execution plus those callbacks are functions generated in their own sandbox I believe so they are like ajax threads they all work separate so nothing working together here to mess it up. How I think?

Comment: Problem isn't with `Number(x)` I tried `console.log("No .moneyFormat() New rate " + (totalPrice / (buyAmount + largessAmount)));` still gives the same result `0.00008499830003399932`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs sometimes when doing claulations using string variables.
Try converting the `buyAmount` and any variable that came from HTML to number before any calculation.

You can use the `Number()` function or `parseFloat()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/rcdmk/63qas2kw/1/

Comment: omg, this is the answer!!!, thank you this is the right answer no wonder! it's with the `if (buyAmount > max) buyAmount = max;` totally missed that, has to be `if (buyAmount > max) buyAmount = parseFloat(max);` same thing with `buyAmount = min;`, But using `buyAmount = parseFloat(buyAmount);` seems to be better to fix it just before calculations.